# Is the browsermob-proxy gem for Ruby not working for anyone else?

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to implement Browsermob Proxy to detect network traffic for something I'm trying to automate, and I've copied the example code in the Github repository to my own code, but the terminal tells me the proxy.har (the har portion) is an undefined method. Upon further inspection, the proxy.rb file is pretty much completely empty, without any defined methods nor constructors.

Here's the github repo:
https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

```
Before ('@selenium_firefox_networkproxy') do
@server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/Users/eliotchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cucumber/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.0.9/lib/browsermob-proxy.rb")
@server.start

@proxy = server.create_proxy

@profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
@profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
:remote,
:url => "http://"+FIREFOX_IP+"/wd/hub",
:desired_capabilities => :firefox,
:profile => @profile)

@proxy.new_har "Analytics"

@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30

@verification_errors = []
end

After ('@selenium_firefox_networkproxy') do
@harfile = @proxy.har
@har.save_to "/Users/eliotchan/Documents/Analytics.har"
@proxy.close
@driver.quit
@verification_errors.should == []
end
```

The error I get is undefined method `har' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: It sounds like a syntax issue, but please post the actual code you are having trouble with along with specific errors you get when you run it.

Comment: @ZachKemp added the code and error

Comment: Is the error associated with the line `@harfile = @proxy.har`? Where does your `Before/After (...) do` syntax come from?

Comment: @ZachKemp Yes, it is. The Before/After is for tags that I put in my .feature files to load certain things for each step. They're in an .env file.

Comment: Ok, so it's likely a cucumber problem. The symptom is that your `@proxy` variable is not persistent. Could you try replacing these with a single `Around` block? Replace `Before` with `Around`, add  `|_,block|` after do, insert `block.call` before `After`, and remove the `After` line.